# why does the executable i created using py2exe only runs on my computer and not on others?

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

The executable i created works completely fine on my system,but as soon as opened in an other system the cmd opens for a very brief time and then closes.

Comment: Most likely the other computers don't have the required dll. It is probably looking for something like `MSVCR90.dll`. It will also have to be the same version that was used to compile the python interpreter. See http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: but i tried that too..!

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt window in windows and execute the .exe from there at the system were it does not work - then you will see the error message why it does not work, and that might help to figure out where the problem is.

If you just double-click the exe the error shows as well, but the cmd window is closed immediately since the process terminates

Comment: thakyou very much..would surely try that.